# Arduino Uno reading a logic 0 signal as 1

Tags: digital-logic, arduino-uno

I have a program on my Arduino Uno that needs to execute quickly, so I'm trying to carry it out by dealing directly with registers. I made a few recent changes to my code, which was originally working fine (unfortunately a change in some of the hardware that's going into this project means I can't revert to the earlier version).

Since the changes, the Uno has developed an issue that I've isolated to one specific problem: I am using an external device to write 0V to the Uno's pin D4 (pinout diagram linked at the bottom of this post), but Serial.print() tells me that pin is getting a 1. I've confirmed the voltage with a multimeter, so either the Arduino is broken or I'm missing something.

```
const uint8_t pinO = 4; // Register D
void setup() {  
     DDRD &= ~(1<<pinO); // sets pin as input
     PORTD &= ~(1<<pinO); // I wasn't sure I needed this line. Is this what I'm doing wrong?
     Serial.begin(9600);
 }

 void loop() {
      Serial.print((PIND >> daqpinO) && 1);
 }
```

There's more to the code, but this is everything that should be relevant to the issue. What I see is that writing 3.3V to a different pin on register D seems to be what's causes this pin to start reading high. That shouldn't be happening though, right? All the GPIO pins should be toggled independently?

https://www.google.com/search?q=arduino+uno+pinout&client=firefox-b-1-d&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=fbbDkYhiQfV2sM%252CFkhuyc9ufXPLnM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kR696oFGr1iYjvDWQkqpvcdtaQOGg&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi13dL9oNHhAhWtIjQIHftuCXkQ_h0wFnoECAsQBA&biw=1536&bih=750#imgrc=fbbDkYhiQfV2sM:&vet=1

Comment: What is it `daqpin0`? Please put all code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this issue might be with your bit math in the print statement.  In the snippet below I've included a typical technique for doing this (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804866/return-a-specific-bit-as-boolean-from-a-byte-value).

Also, your second line clearing the bit in PORTD after having set it as an input by clearing DDRD will effectively disable the input pull-up resistor on that input.  If the source driving your input can drive both high and low (push-pull) that shouldn't be an issue, but if you're just shorting the input to ground (i.e. with a switch or open collector output) you may have undefined behavior (floating input) when the input isn't actively driven.  See Arduino's page on port manipulation for more info:

- https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PortManipulation
- https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/digitalwrite/

```
    const uint8_t pinO = 4; // Register D
    
    void setup() {  
         // Clearing DDRD sets the pin to input mode
         DDRD &= ~(1<<pinO);
         // This is the equivalent of digitalWrite and will disable the input pull-up
         PORTD &= ~(1<<pinO);
         
         Serial.begin(9600);
     }
    
     void loop() {
          //Serial.print((PIND >> daqpinO) && 1); <-- This looks like it could be your issue
          //Proposed snippet for checking a bit using a bit-mask
          Serial.print((PIND & (1<<pinO)) != 0);
     }
```

### Edit 1

Added details on why precisely the original version is not working:

Your original statement: `(PIND >> daqpinO) && 1` is inadvertently True when pin numbers above 4 are set.  This is because `&&` is a *LOGICAL* AND statement and not a *BITWISE* AND statement.  As an example: let's say that `pinO` is written LOW and that pin 6 on PORTD is currently written HIGH.  The port status would be `PIND = 0b01000000`.  The result of your original statement would be:

```
    (PIND >> pinO) = 0b00000100
    // Logical AND operation will return True because (PIND >> pinO) is non-zero
    0b00000100 && 1 = True
    // Bitwise AND operation would have returned the intended result 
    // because it would mask out more significant bits
    0b00000100 & 1 = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single & instead if && to fix it. You need a bitwise AND, not logical AND.

Answer (score -1):

Your pin0 is set as an input. You cannot be writing to it. So your statement PORTD &=~(1<

Comment: Writing to PORTD register controls the internal pull-up. So it is normal to write it. In this case it turns the pull-up off.